# trying to load electron.BrowserWindow into an aurelia app

Tags: node.js, aurelia, electron

I'm trying to import electron into my aurelia app but I can not, if I use import it does not find de folder where electron is, if I change the import to use the exact folder then it seems to begin to load but then fails to find drip, which I installed but electron seems to search for it in the wrong folder to :(. So I tried to use require to load it but it give's me a 'require is not a function', that is when I find your comment where you propose to import require so I installed npm:require but when I try to imorte it aurelia cant either.
So my question is: can someone help me to load electron into my aurelia app?
thanks!.